# What is the best way to calculate a flat rate shipping cost for an order on Spree with two stock locations?

Tags: spree

If a customer has an order with one product from each of my two stock locations locations, then the flat-rate shipping per an order is applied twice. I don't want to pass the second shipping cost to the customer, but rather only apply one flat-rate shipping expense. What is the best way to do this that will have the least impact for Spree Core?

Comment: We need to see your code to help you

Comment: What do you want to see? This is all default Spree configuration. If you setup a new Spree project, with two stock locations and ship a variant from each stock location then flat-rate shipping is applied twice. This occurs in Spree::Stock::Coordinator. It is based per a shipment not per order. I am trying to figure out how to make it per order.

Comment: we'd like you to attempt on your own and once you get stuck, you can post your code and login on stack and we'll do our best to help out.